# Asp.net: The type or namespace name 'Entity' does not exist in the namespace 'DataManager' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, ado.net

I added a class library to an API project to get the data from database. In the class library "DataManager" I created a folder named "Entity" and added ADO entity data models for for sql and oracle db. When I was creating the ADO for oracle I had to degrade entity framework version from 6 to 5.

Models.Context.cs

```
namespace DataManger.Entity
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
    
    public partial class myEntities : DbContext
    {
        public myEntities()
            : base("name=myEntities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }
    
        public DbSet<Application> Applications { get; set; }
```

Now when I try to get any of the models in "Entity".

```
using DataManager.Entity;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace DataManager.Services
{
    public class ApplicationDataService : IApplicationDataService
    {
```

I get the following error message in the first line when using DataManager.Entity

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Entity' does not exist in the namespace 'DataManager' (are you missing an assembly reference?)  DataManger  ......

Comment: Provide more information and share your code.

Comment: Typo?  DataManger.Entity vs DataManager.Entity?